# Creating a 'Letter Grade' array from an array that contains total score

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy and am having issues with this line of code. I am trying to make an array of letter grades from an array of final scores, but keep coming across the following error message:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```py
import numpy as np

def letterGrade(score): 
#returns corresponding letter grade for given numerical score
    grade = 'unknown'
    
    if score >= 93 and score <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif score >= 90 and score <= 92.99:
        grade = 'A-'
    elif score >= 86 and score <= 89.99:
        grade = 'B+'
    elif score >= 83 and score <= 85.99:
        grade = 'B'
    elif score >= 80 and score <= 82.99:
        grade = 'B-'
    elif score >= 76 and score <= 79.99:
        grade = 'C+'
    elif score >= 73 and score <= 75.99:
        grade = 'C'
    elif score >= 70 and score <= 72.99:
        grade = 'C-'
    elif score >= 66 and score <= 69.99:
        grade = 'D+'
    elif score >= 60 and score <= 65.99:
        grade = 'D'
    elif score >= 0 and score <= 59.99:
        grade = 'F'        
    elif score < 0 or score > 100:
        grade = 'can not be determined from the input given'
    return grade    



def main():
    
    score_headings = np.load("C:/Users/Javy/Downloads/score_headings.npy")
    total = score_headings[:,1:].sum(axis=1)
    total = np.array(total)
    
    ltrGrd = letterGrade(total)
   
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are passing an `numpy.ndarray` object to a function that expects an atomic integer. Python won't apply the function to each element of the vector automatically (as R would, e.g.). To solve this you just have to apply the function to each item individually. Here's one way to do that:

```
ltrGrd = list(map(lambda x: letterGrade(x), total))
```